# about uninstalling mysql and installing xampp mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, xampp

I had installed mysql5 on my laptop, I uninstalled  mysql 5  and installed xampp,
but xampp can't run mysql it shows following error message

> Mysql detected wrong pathunistall and disable other service 
>       firstfoundpath:"c:programfiles\mysql\mysqlserver5.0\bin\mysqld-nt"--defaults file=c:programfiles\mysql\mysqlserver5.0\my.ini Mysql
>       expectedpath=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe--defaults file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql

I had deleted mysql folder from program files, but still it showing the same error message,please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps

- Uninstall mysql from machine then restart it.
- Delete `MySQL` folder from `"C:/Program Files/"` and `"C:/Program Files(86)/"` if present.
- Delete `MySQL` folder from `"C:/Program Data/"` folder is present. (If you can't see `Program Data` folder, then goto `Folder Options -> View -> Show hidden files, folders and drives -> Apply -> Ok`).
- Delete `MySQL` folder from `"C:\Users\<Current User>\AppData\Roaming"` if present.
- And then install XAMPP.

**Step 3 helped me in my case.** So don't forget to do so.

Hope it'll help.